# IBM DB/2 i - SQL SELECT JSON_VAL FROM Json_Table"

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to work through example of using "SQL SELECT JSON_VAL FROM Json_Table" 
to get data from remote web service.  I keep getting variation of the same error...

Position 17 INTO clause missing from embedded statement.

Can anyone guide me?  IBM i (as/400) DB/2 OS/V7R3M0

thanks!

```
// JSON_TABLE : used to extract values from that JSON object into relational data.   
// '$' :  used as the outermost SQL/JSON path expression,                            
//        the column definitions will use the existing JSON object                   
//        as their context item. Because '$' only references one item in the         
//        object, this use of JSON_TABLE will only produce one row.                  
//        After the outermost SQL/JSON path expression, the columns are defined.     


     D myString     s           5500a    

      Exec SQL SELECT JSON_VAL FROM Json_Table(                            
      Systools.HttpPostClob(                                               
        'http://10.10.10.10:8099/dir/dir/pgm',              
        '<httpHeader>' +                                                   
        '<header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>' +         
        '</httpHeader>',  :myString       
        // '</httpHeader>' INTO :myString    << NO   
        // '</httpHeader>') INTO :myString    << NO
       ), '$' COLUMNS(JSON_VAL VARCHAR(1000) PATH '$.json')) as x ;        


       ParmOut = myString;
```

Comment: Invalid SQL. The embedded-format is SELECT whatever INTO ... FROM ...". Also JSON_VAL is a function (it needs arguments, you show none). Refer to documentation. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070286.html

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT INTO` syntax goes like this:

```
exec sql
  select ...
    into ...
    from ...
```

So try this:

```
exec sql
  select json_val
    into :mystring
    from json_table(
      systools.HttpPostClob(
        'http://10.10.10.10:8099/dir/dir/pgm',              
        '<httpHeader>' +                                                   
        '<header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>' +         
        '</httpHeader>'
      ), '$' COLUMNS(JSON_VAL VARCHAR(1000) PATH '$.json')) as x ;
```

Problem is, I can't find HttpPostClob() in the DB2 for i v7.3 documentation. It might not be something you can use on that platform without rolling your own stored procedure.

Comment: It looks like this feature was stealthy added in 7.2 or 73.  See reference to it here http://ibmsystemsmag.com/blogs/i-can/january-2017/json_table-function/

Comment: I think my problem might be that response might have to be captured with SQL Cursor and SQL Fetch Next loop.. Again not too familiar with this stuff.